# Embeding Quick Animation/SWF in an SVG element

Tags: jquery, flash, d3.js, svg

I'm stuck...I have this project built with D3.js and HTML5, so I'm using a lot of d3 animations with elements such as bar graphs, pie charts, etc. However, my company now want some sort of logo for our company designed. Now, they want this logo to have different animations.

So, essentially there's 2 parts. There's the logo that's being designed/created with all the animations (Not a part of d3.js. That's a completely separate project that we are outsourcing). Then there's my project built on d3.js.

So, I don't know what file type I need to request back from the animator. I need to be able to embed on an existing svg element.

I've tried fooling around and see if I can get an swf file on the svg, but I'm not having any luck. I did realize that I can add a .GIF file and it works, but I feel like we should get an actual .swf file or something "official" for animations. Here's what I've tried for embedding the .swf file:

svg.append("embed").attr("src": "x");

I've also tried:

svg.append("object").attr("data": "x")
    .append("embed").attr("src": "x");

It shows the tags in dev tools, but it isn't rendering on the page..Any suggestions?

Comment: Take care about "it shows the tags in dev tools". Everything shows up in the dev tools, but it doesn't mean it's valid. For instance, if you do `svg.append("charlesdarwin")` you will have: `<svg><charlesdarwin></charlesdarwin></svg>`, but it will not work, of course...

Comment: Why not do the logo in SVG too. The logo can then be animated with SMIL, CSS or javascript and adding it to your existing SVG should be pretty straightforward if you already know how SVG works.

Comment: @RobertLongson, the logo is being outsourced. Most likely done by artists not coders so the animator probably won't like to write CSS and JavaScript etc for a moving result.

Comment: if you want to embed flash in SVG you'll need to put the flash in an object tag and put the object tag in a foreignObject tag. IE does not support foreignObject though. Alternatively embed the swf in the html page and use absolute positioning to position the SVG on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash can output SVG. 
Check these **[google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=lose&oq=lose&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65l3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=flash+output+SVG+animation)** and then suggest something to your outsourced designer.

If they are on the latest version this feature is built-in : **[see video guide](https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/how-to/export-image-svg.html)**

If they are using CS 5 / CS 5.5 or CS 6 they can try this add-on:  **[Flash 2 SVG](https://github.com/TomByrne/Flash2Svg)**

Comment: So, when they output it to SVG, it should just be as easy as appending it to the existing canvas, right?

Comment: You could also use CSS layers (z indexing) to put the logo on its own top-most layer (floating) above other content.